# Copy filename from directoriy into generic list

Tags: c#, list, directory, getfiles

I have a weird behavior and not sure where to go from here. I am trying to read filename from a directory and add that to the generic list of type `<string>`.

```
string path = @"C:\mydir\";

foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.bak").Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName))
{
    GenericList1.Add(s);

}
```

I get the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I Debug, I see that the variable `s` displays the filename as the value. Infact I can see the value when I use:

```
foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.bak").Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName))
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s);           
}
```

Anyone has any insight where I might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.bak").Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p)))
        {
            GenericList1.Add(s);

        }
```

That `Select` method requires a function to perform on each object. The easiest way to do this is to use a simple lambda.

You are basically creating an anonymous method or function when using lambda. The `Select` method needs to know what function or action you want to take on each item of a collection. In this case you want to get the file name of each item in the collection that is returned by `GetFiles` method. If you want more of an explanation let me know.

Comment: HI Adrian, I used the lambba and still get the same null value passed into the list even though the variable itself contains the actual file name. I am attempting whats suggested under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694676/how-do-i-retrieve-all-filenames-in-a-directory

Comment: Actually, I did work around by inserting the data into an array and then adding that array into Generic List. So I have the solution. But curious about the original question though

Comment: Can you put your code that is working on a pastebucket and send me the link here? I'm curious as to why it's not working for you too. There shouldn't be any problems

Comment: string[] filenames =  {  };

Comment: string[] filenames = { }; 
list GenericList1  = new list();

filenames = Directory.GetFiles(foldername, "*.txt").Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
                       
 if (filenames .Length > 0)
   {
                            
   GenericList1 = filenames.ToList();

  }